# Execution failed for task ':arcore_flutter_plugin:compileDebugKotlin' in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, arcore

I want to use Arcore plugin in Flutter  but it had this error.

> Launching lib\main.dart on Pixel 2 XL in debug mode...
> lib\main.dart:1
> e: C:\src\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\arcore_flutter_plugin-0.0.11\android\src\main\kotlin\com\difrancescogianmarco\arcore_flutter_plugin\ArCoreView.kt: (245, 38): Object is not abstract and does not implement abstract member public abstract fun onActivityCreated(p0: Activity, p1: Bundle?): Unit defined in android.app.Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks
> e: C:\src\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\arcore_flutter_plugin-0.0.11\android\src\main\kotlin\com\difrancescogianmarco\arcore_flutter_plugin\ArCoreView.kt: (246, 13): 'onActivityCreated' overrides nothing

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

> What went wrong:
> Execution failed for task ':arcore_flutter_plugin:compileDebugKotlin'.

> Compilation error. See log for more details

> Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

> BUILD FAILED in 1m 17s
> Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Can someone help me to solve this please

Answer (score 1):

Did you add some configurations for arcode package;
(By the way, this plugin can be used just in android. if you are testing on ios device, it's not gonna work)

Modify your AndroidManifest.xml to include the following entries:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

<!-- Limits app visibility in the Google Play Store to ARCore supported devices
     (https://developers.google.com/ar/devices). -->
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.ar" />

<application …>
    …

    <!-- "AR Required" app, requires "Google Play Services for AR" (ARCore)
         to be installed, as the app does not include any non-AR features. -->
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.ar.core" android:value="required" />
</application>
```

Then, ensure that your app has at least the required minSdkVersion in your app's build.gradle:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        …
        minSdkVersion 24
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility 1.8
        targetCompatibility 1.8
    }
}
```

Add the latest ARCore library as a dependency in your app's build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.ar.sceneform.ux:sceneform-ux:1.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.ar:core:1.30.0'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

***If doing the above still fails and shows CompileDebugKotlin error then this should finish the job***

Found a solution, modify two files blow.
I don't know kotlin, but basically it is a nullable problem. @giandifra
../arcore_flutter_plugin-master/android/src/main/kotlin/com/difrancescogianmarco/arcore_flutter_plugin/ArCoreViewFactory.kt
line 14 from
override fun create(context: Context, id: Int, args: Any?): PlatformView {

to

override fun create(context: Context?, id: Int, args: Any?): PlatformView {

line 25 from
return ArCoreFaceView(activity, context, messenger, id, debug)

to

return ArCoreFaceView(activity, context!!, messenger, id, debug)

line 28 from
return ArCoreAugmentedImagesView(activity, context, messenger, id, useSingleImage, debug)

to
return ArCoreAugmentedImagesView(activity, context!!, messenger, id, useSingleImage, debug)

line 30 from
return ArCoreAugmentedImagesView(activity, context, messenger, id, useSingleImage, debug)

to
return ArCoreAugmentedImagesView(activity, context!!, messenger, id, useSingleImage, debug)

../arcore_flutter_plugin-master/android/src/main/kotlin/com/difrancescogianmarco/arcore_flutter_plugin/ArcoreFlutterPlugin.kt

line 32 from
.registerViewFactory(CHANNEL_NAME, ArCoreViewFactory(registrar.activity(), registrar.messenger()))

to

.registerViewFactory(CHANNEL_NAME, ArCoreViewFactory(registrar.activity()!!, registrar.messenger()))